# Would a Monk wearing Mage Armor still lose his Fast Movement, Flurry of Blows, and other abilities?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, armor

If I were playing a Monk wearing Mage Armor, would I still lose my Fast Movement, Flurry of Blows, and other abilities I normally lose when wearing normal armor?

Answer (score 12):

## A monk can use abilities that require no armor if protected by *mage armor*

While the spell [*mage armor*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mage-armor/) grants the subject an armor bonus the same way that real armor grants an armor bonus, the subject is *not* wearing armor and, instead, the subject of the *mage armor* spell is surrounded by an "invisible but tangible field of force."

While it may seem a technical and pedantic distinction between being enveloped by the invisible field of a *mage armor* spell and, for example, slapping on a chain shirt, [monk](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/) class features that are contingent upon a monk not wearing armor like AC bonus, [fast movement](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Monk/#TOC-Fast-Movement-Ex-), and [flurry of blows](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Monk/#Flurry_of_Blows_Ex) really are unaffected by the spell *mage armor* even though they would be affected by a chain shirt: a chain shirt is, in game terms, *worn* and the effect of the *mage armor* spell isn't. (This is likewise true of the similar class features of the [unchained monk](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/monk-unchained/).)

Comment: A comparison to the _bracers of armor_ might add to this answer.

Answer (score 6):

## A monk retains his class features because having an armor bonus to AC is not the same as wearing armor.

A monk loses access to some of his class features while wearing armor. However, the game has many ways to gain an **armor bonus** without wearing armor. The *mage armor* spell, *bracers of armor,* and the ice armor oracle revelation from the [waves mystery](https://www.aonprd.com/MysteryDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Waves) are a few examples. The same principle applies to shield bonuses.

**Simply having an armor bonus or shield bonus does not count as physically wearing armor or a shield.** The *mage armor* spell simply grants its target an armor bonus. Thus, a monk under the effects of *mage armor* does not lose access to class features that forbid wearing armor.

You can find numerous official NPC stat blocks of monks with *potions of mage armor* and *bracers of armor*, such as [these](https://aonprd.com/NPCDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Careful%20Initiate) [two](https://aonprd.com/NPCDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Ageless%20Master). In Pathfinder Society, it is common for monk players to carry a *wand of mage armor* for arcane party members to cast on them.